# Whoisxmlapi API is not running

Tags: whois

This API http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=xxxxxx is returning an error message as xml format.

```
<ErrorMessage>
<msg>
IP Address 203.100.79.84 has 0/50 queries available, please refill
</msg>
</ErrorMessage>
```

Can any one help me to sort this out. I need proper `xml` for a registered domain.

Comment: The error is self explanatory, you've used up 50 free queries from your IP. You'll need to [**pay**](http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/hosted_pricing.php) up..

Comment: Did you ask the provider of the service?

Answer (score 0):

You're only allowed 50 queries for a free account. Check [this page](http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/hosted_pricing.php) for options if you want to upgrade.